# Prove that $\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{2}{a_1+a_2} + \frac{3}{a_1+a_2+a_3}<2(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove that $$\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{2}{a_1+a_2} + \frac{3}{a_1+a_2+a_3}<2(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}) $$ where $a_1, a_2, a_3 >0$.
From AM-HM I got that $\frac{2}{a_1+a_2}\le \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2})$ and $\frac{3}{a_1+a_2+a_3}\le \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3})$, but adding these is not enough.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, adding these inequalities *is* good enough. You get $\frac{11}{6} \frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{5}{6} \frac{1}{a_2} + \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{a_3}$

Comment: It is good enough, indeed! $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} < 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to my comment and your progress with AM-HM
$$\frac{1}{a_1}<\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}$$
$$\frac{2}{a_1+a_2}\leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}\right)<\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}\right)$$
$$\frac{3}{a_1+a_2+a_3}\leq \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}\right)$$
Add together
$$\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{2}{a_1+a_2}+\frac{3}{a_1+a_2+a_3}<\color{red}{\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)}\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}\right)<\color{red}{2}\cdot ...$$

Comment: This solution,I see feels a bit more elegant actually. Thanks for the simplification.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the inequalities given by you:
$$\dfrac{1}{a_1}+\dfrac{2}{a_1+a_2}+\dfrac{3}{a_1+a_2+a_3}<\dfrac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}}{a_1}+\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}}{a_2}+\dfrac{\frac{1}{3}}{a_3}$$
$$\dfrac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}}{a_1}+\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}}{a_2}+\dfrac{\frac{1}{3}}{a_3}<\dfrac{2}{a_1}+\dfrac{2}{a_2}+\dfrac{2}{a_3}$$
$\therefore \dfrac{1}{a_1}+\dfrac{2}{a_1+a_2}+\dfrac{3}{a_1+a_2+a_3}<\dfrac{2}{a_1}+\dfrac{2}{a_2}+\dfrac{2}{a_3}$

Comment: I must admit, you re-grouping is right, but a bit "asking for more concentration", thus, I posted my answer ... +1 from me anyway.